# How to return a random integer from a two parameters function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I would like to know how to write a function that takes two two arrays of integers, `a` and `b`, and returns an array containing two integers, one chosen randomly from `a` and the other chosen randomly from `b`.

For example:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
var b = [5,6,7,8];

function randomInt(a, b)
{ 
   // ....
}

randomInt(a, b); // should return an array of two integers, e.g. [2,7]
```

Comment: So you'd pass for instance 4 and 5 to the function, and it returns one of those randomly selected, like 4 ?

Comment: You mean that if you pass for example 3 and 6, it would return 3, 4, 5 or 6?

Comment: sorry, what i mean is, a has 1,2,3,4  b has 5,6,7,8 the function should return a random int, for example  [3, 8].

Comment: @user2995331: So the parameters are *arrays* of integers? And the result should be an array with two items, one picked randomly from each of the two arrays?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right. Sorry if it was confusing.

Comment: @user2995331: Yes, it was a bit confusing. :) I added a solution for that below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of numbers is the difference between the limits plus one. This returns a random number between `min` and `max`, both inclusive:

```
function rnd(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Usage example:

```
var dice = rnd(1, 6);
```

#### Edit:

With the clarified question:

```
function rnd(arr1, arr2) {
  return [
    arr1[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr1.length)],
    arr2[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr2.length)]
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function randomInt(a, b)
 { 
   var first = Math.floor(Math.random() * (a.length));
   var second = Math.floor(Math.random() * (b.length));
   console.log(a[first]);
   console.log(",");
   console.log(b[second]);
   return [a[first],b[second]];
 }
```

so as i understood a and b are arrays?
can you show more examples like "1,2,3,4 b has 5,6,7,8 the function should return a random int, for example [3, 8]"